# How do I get the resource name of elements in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

On the Google Play Console I am trying to get the information to fill out the following:

[image: resouce name fields on Google Play Console]

I can see my sign in page on the screenshots tab of the pre-launch report, but I can't figure out how to actually get the resource names for the three elements. I am using Auth0, and the page I'm trying to get the resource names from looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3ECp.png).

Any advice on how to get this information would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it to be supported for WebView based apps like Cordova.

From: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en

> **Additional testing features**
>
> **How are credentials used?**
>
> **Note:** Credentials can only be automatically inserted into Android apps that use standard Android widgets. Credentials can't be used in apps that use OpenGL to render custom controls or apps that use a WebView for a web-based authentication flow.